# tabulator scrollbars missing when you set height

Tags: javascript, tabulator

not sure if this is a bug or as designed.  I successfully tried to set the height of my table programatically using `table.setHeight()` but i was not given any scroll bars.

If I set the height on the table constructor `height:300` then I have scroll bars even if i resize programatically later.

Is that the intended behavior? seems like a wasted step.

Comment: I'm also seeing similar behavior

Answer (score 0):

In certain scenarios, you may need to call the ***redraw*** function on the table after setting its height

```js
table.redraw(true);
```